# How to check for updates while app is closed in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, service, android-activity

So here is my case. I have one main activity and when I start it I fetch some data from a local server via JSON in an AsyncTask and store that data in an ArrayList.
Also when I launch the app I start a service which is polling data from the server every X seconds. I use an intent to send that arrayList to the service so it can compare and see if there are any changes. The service is supposed to run all the time even if the app is closed.
All that is managed so far but I did a big mistake not storing the initially fetched data from the activity in SQLite or something like that.
Do you think its a good idea to do that ? Using SQLite for checking for updates ? 
I also forgot to mention that if I close the app and when the service tries to compare it gets a nullpointer because I assume the activity does not exist anymore once I stop it.

I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is simple enough, just try storing it in SharedPreferences. It'll avoid a lot of SQL headaches.

You can just fetch that data from the service instead of using Intents as well. Keep it simple!